# Terminated due to memory issue : when I take 5 GB video file from photo library

Tags: ios, file, video, uiimagepickercontroller

I was trying to take a video file into my app directory.
When I choose 5GB video file by UIImagePickerController, it needs to behold on for a while compressing video.
After compressing the app gets crashed on iPad: 
Communications error: Connection interrupted
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

With iPhone works fine if it has enough space of storage.
But on iPad, it always gets above issue.

I see the memory session in Debug Session tab of XCode, it was 900 MB just on compressing video file from photo library.
I guess iPhone has stronger memory performance than iPad.

Is this related to memory session?
I'd like to know why it works like this and solves for this issue.